# Using etoolbox macros in tikz foreach loops

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach, etoolbox

I am trying to wrap my head around `etoolbox` for use with TikZ. In this **example** (I know there are probably simpler ways to do this), I would like to draw a series of rectangles that are next to each other. In general, the approach is to start with one rectangle, declare a point diagonal to the rectangle origin, and draw the rectangle to that point. I would then iterate with the TikZ `\foreach` command to create 15 such blocks.
At the moment, my code looks like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,%
shapes.symbols,%
shapes.misc,%
fit,%
positioning,%
decorations.pathmorphing,%
decorations.pathreplacing,%
decorations.text,%
shadows,%
fadings}

\providetoggle{isodd} 

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[%
scale=0.5
]

\coordinate (bar-origin) at (0,0) ;
\coordinate[above right=50mm and 148mm of bar-origin] (bar0) ; 

\foreach \x in {1,2,...,15}{%
\pgfmathparse{\x-1}
\iftoggle{isodd}{\global\togglefalse{isodd}%
    \coordinate[above right=50mm and 34mm of bar\pgfmathresult]  (bar\x) ; 
}%
{\global\toggletrue{isodd}
    \coordinate[below right=50mm and 34mm of bar\pgfmathresult]  (bar\x) ; 
}%

\draw[fill=green,draw=black] (bar\pgfmathresult) rectangle (bar\x) ; 

}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**EDIT:** above code works. Thanks!

Rest assured that `\providetoggle{isodd}` is earlier in the code. Strangely enough, it looks like this code produces some kind of infinite loop. That is, `pdflatex` is hanging while still consuming a processor's worth of power. What am I doing wrong, and how could I accomplish this in a similar way?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. `\pgfmathparse{\x-1}` gives nothing but `\pgfmathresult` holds the result. Also `\x-1` would give a decimal such as 1.0 so you have to truncate it. Please complete your examples to a MWE such that we can directly copy/paste and see the problem. Otherwise we can only read your code and that's not always feasible.

Comment: Each step of a `\foreach` cycle is performed in a group; use `\global` before `\toggletrue` and `\togglefalse`. However the code is anyway faulty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apologies in advance for not quite understanding what the code should suppose to do but here is a literal translation without `etoolbox` as far as I can read your code.

```
%Required \usetikzlibrary{positioning} in the preamble

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]

\coordinate (bar-origin) at (0,0) ;
\coordinate[above right=50mm and 148mm of bar-origin] (bar0) ;

\foreach \x[remember=\x as \lastx(initially 0)] in {1,2,...,15}{
\pgfmathparse{Mod(\x,2)<1?"below right":"above right"}
\coordinate[\pgfmathresult=50mm and 34mm of bar\lastx] (bar\x);
\draw[fill=green,draw=black] (bar\lastx) rectangle (bar\x); 
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Same result can also be achieved using nodes.

Answer (score 7):

Each step in a `\foreach` cycle is performed in a group, so the change of the toggle is not seen outside.

Use `\global\toggletrue{isodd}` and `\global\togglefalse{isodd}`.

As percusse notes in a comment, also the use of `\pgfmathparse` should be fixed:

> `\pgfmathparse{\x-1}` gives nothing but `\pgfmathresult` holds the result.